# Disable Waiting on Paths for Transporters blocking the way

Tags: anylogic

This might be a silly question, but I figured I'd ask.

My model uses Transporters from the MHL as pickers within a warehouse. They follow a set network of unidirectional paths. I figured that Transporters were the ideal agent type to use in this case, given that simulating congestion was one of the objectives of the model.

However, the next step is now to measure the impact of congestion by comparing it with a scenario where the pickers *did not have to wait after one another*.

Is there any way to make so Transporters can "pass through" each other?

My tried workaround has been to switch the Transporters over to free-space navigation set their size to near 0, and carefully order their destinations to imitate the series of unidirectional paths, but their behavior is not exactly as desired.

I'm guessing the next workable solution would be to rebuild the logic using the PML, given that my network is already built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer still stands.
The even easier solution that still makes use of the MHL would be to use `transporter.ignoreCollisions(boolean)` on all Transporters in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Drag in a `TransporterControl` block next to your flow chart and disable collisions:
[image]

Note: If your flow chart spans several agent types, you need one of those on each agent type

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I have already tried that. I don't believe AnyLogic treats Transporters waiting for another that is performing a task/paused in from of it a "collision". Here is an example https://ibb.co/qdXJbgS. The Transporter at the bottom is performing a task. Even with "Avoid Collision" unticked, the Transporters above it will never "pass through" it.

Comment: Please always tell us what you already tried ;) See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-creating the logic using PML blocks, and replacing the "Move by Transporter" blocks with Seize blocks on a mobile resource. It doesn't exactly recreate the desired behaviour, but will serve as an appropriate stopgap for now.